# Replacing NA's in data frame with 0, cases still not showing up in output R

Tags: r, replace, na

Here's the directory with CSV files I'm using:
https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/rprog%2Fdata%2Fspecdata.zip

here's my code:

```
complete<- function(directory, id=1:332){
    data<-NULL
    for (i in 1:length(id)) {
            data[[i]]<- c(paste(directory, "/",formatC(id[i], width=3, flag=0),".csv",sep=""))     
    }
    cases<-NULL
    for (d in 1:length(data)) { 
            cases[[d]]<-c(read.csv(data[d]))
    }
    df<-NULL
    for (c in 1:length(cases)){
            df[[c]]<-(data.frame(cases[c]))
    }
    dt<-do.call(rbind, df)
    ok<-(complete.cases(dt))

    finally<-as.data.frame(table(dt[ok, "ID"]))
    colnames(finally)<-c('id', 'nobs')
    replace(finally,is.na(finally),0)
    return(finally)

}
```

when I  enter:
`complete('specdata')`
I get a data frame with the number of complete cases in each csv file but the CSV files with no complete cases are omitted completely.  I need the csv files with 0 complete cases to show up in the data frame with a nobs value of 0. I tried using replace in the code but it doesn't seem to change my data frame at all.

Comment: FYI, this is homework for the Coursera R class, for those of you familiar with it (week 2).  @questioner, my advice is that this is way, way too complicated for the actual needs of `complete`.  Read the cases in, then use the R function for counting cases and tell it to count only complete cases.  If you've watched the week 3 videos, `sapply` is helpful here.

Comment: Just remove the `complete.cases` line and the `NaN` and zero observation lines will show up. Curious, do they tell you what the answers are, so you can check your work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a data frame `df`, `complete.cases(df)` returns a vector of true or false values. You can use this vector as an index of `df` to extract a subset of it that has complete cases, like this:

```
df[complete.cases(df),]
```

The number of complete cases, or `nobs` value as you write in your text, is the number of rows in this resulting smaller data frame. You can use the `nrow` function to get that count:

```
nrow(df[complete.cases(df),])
```

This will return 0 for a data frame that has no complete cases.

To solve the exercise, you need to build a data frame with two vectors: `id` and `nobs`, where `nobs` is the number of complete cases of the data frame indicated by the corresponding `id`. For getting the `nobs` value from the `id`, it makes sense to introduce a helper function:

```
get.nobs <- function(id) {
  df <- getmonitor(id, directory)
  nrow(df[complete.cases(df),])
}
```

`getmonitor` is a function to read the data frame from a csv file. After you have the data frame for this id, you can return the row count of the complete cases in it.

You can use this function to get the count for each id. Instead of a loop, this is a perfect use case for `sapply`.

Putting it all together (**spoiler alert!**):

> ```
>  complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
>    get.nobs <- function(id) {
>      df <- getmonitor(id, directory)
>      nrow(df[complete.cases(df),])
>    }
>    data.frame(id, nobs=sapply(id, get.nobs))
>  }
> ```